# How to remove cursor from editable QComboBox when I either press enter or click mouse outside its area?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qlineedit

I have a QComboBox which is made editable. When I type some text in it and press enter, it is performing its action. But the cursor still blinks in the text box. And even if by mistake I press any UP/DOWN key the item is changing.

How to remove this blinking cursor if I press enter or click mouse outside its area?

Comment: Some code would be nice for context, although this is actually a pretty thorough description.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is the standard behavior of a combo box, in Qt or in any other toolkit. If you want that cursor to stop blinking, then give the keyboard focus to another widget. You can call [`QWidget::setFocus()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus-1) on another widget of your application. Also have a look at the general documentation about focus in Qt5, [*Keyboard Focus in Widgets*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/focus.html), to get more input on keyboard focus.

Comment: Thanks @Irineau. SetFocusPolicy to the central widget did the job as described in the link.